# 'You are good' - meaning while in conference call

Tags: american-english

As part of our (USA)customer call. He informed the participants that 'The call is over. and you may drop off from conference.'

Since I was not sure about dropping off the call, I asked 'Shall I drop off?"

Customer replied with one statement 'You are good'.

So just wanted to understand what does that response mean - 'You are good to drop off' or 'You are good to be on call'

Thank you!

PS: As I was in dilemma - I continued with the call - As mute participant of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from my experience in technology and working in cross functional teams.
You're good means your previous statement holds true

> Me :"Shall I migrate the database"
>
> Client: "You're Good"

The client here just affirms that I should do whatever I had previously stated.

So the client meant that you should drop the call

Comment: Also, the client was being polite not to say outright, "Yes, get off the call."

Answer (score 2):

"You are good" means "no problem" here. It means they are fine with you dropping off.

Answer (score 1):

**Sometimes, AmE speakers can sound like sports' referees. Too much football. Drop off a team? Drop off a conference call is to disconnect from it. 
Since English speakers are enamored of two-word verbs, they often find a way around a longer, Latin-based verb. But the image does make me think of monkeys hanging from a vine (a kind of line, right?) across a space between two trees and suddenly dropping off it.

Seriously, though, there is semantic logic to this expression, which I believe I have managed to extricate (dig out, two-word verb):

To wit,  we say to **BE ON THE LINE** (be speaking or listening on a phone line), to **NOT BE ON THE LINE** (not be speaking or listening on a phone line. That is the traditional way one talks about whether or not a person is participating in a telephone call at either end of a call.

Ergo, it makes sense that, if, of one's own volition, one disconnects from the line, one IS DROPPING OFF the line to which others are connected. One might think that ****drop out of the line**** would work, but it doesn't unless you are standing in line for a movie or theater.

So, back to my monkeys hanging from the line. They drop off the line (let go of it, "disconnect from it") just as a conference caller drops off the (telephone) line (disconnects from it).

How does that grab you?

By the way, a quick Ngram of conference call, drop off produced a line for both but they did not cross at all. Interesting...since, if you google conference call + drop off  you get many hits.

Finally, I did find one hit in a book called Private Telecommunications Networks to back-up this general idea. But really, looking no further than everyday telephone language would seem to suffice. One just needs to add the monkeyish imagination.